# keyboard command to focus on erroneous text in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: intellij-idea

In eclipse when you hover over some erroneous text you can press `F2` to focus there. What is the equivalent procedure in IntelliJ?

Whenever I put my pointer over some error the text describing it disappears.

In Eclipse it will suggest what I can do to fix something like an *unhandled IO exception*. I'm sure IntelliJ can also do this because some people I know who are quite skillful programmers highly recommended it to me, but- how to do this?

---

That is: hover over some text at is in error, see what the error is, the options to fix it, and then choose one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the highlighted part of code, the error description will appear in a pop-up bubble as well as in statusbar.

You can then hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> which will offer you some options to handle the given error/warning or to disable the warning.

Comment: but so far `ALT`+`ENTER` only is one solution, is that becase it can only find one solution to those problems? I think it's annoying to read the error from that status bar on the bottom of the screen, you mean it can't just give focus to the pop-window and prevent that from disappearing as eclipse does?

Comment: Depends on the problem. For some warnings/errors such as unhandled checked exception multiple actions are offered (add to method signature, surround with try catch). For some problems just one solution, for other problems no automatic fixes can be performed.

Answer (score 1):

The actions you are looking for is called "Error Description" and "Show Intention Actions".

- ⌘+F1 (Ctrl+F1 on non-mac) will show the error info on based on where the caret is.
- Alt+Enter will show the Intention Actions available based of the location of the caret.